# iOS 9 AutoLayout nightmares iPad fighting back

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, ios9

**Note: I have discarded this layout entirely for a redesign. I'm still curious if there is an answer to this, but it no longer is necessary for my purposes.**

I am dealing with what should basically be a 3 element layout.
2 elements are 3:2, 1 is 1:1.
The goal is to have them aligned:
 Landscape:  8-3:2-8-1:1-8-3:2- on the bottom
 Portrait: 8-3:2->=8-3:2-8 w/ this line 8 space to the next >=8-1:1->=8 which is on the bottom.

Illustration attached.

I've tried doing simple attaches (any W, any H) on the basics:

- 3:2

  - always pinned to the left/right edges

    Same size

    tops aligned to each other

- 1:1 - always pinned to the bottom edges

Once I start trying to set up compact height and width things start okay, however between the iPad and the 1/3 width things start fighting each other.
I've been trying to suss this out for the better part of a month restarting basically from scratch each time. And suggestions are warmly welcome.

I've attached a layout graphic. All spacing is standard 8'ish in size. The red lines represent places that variable width is fine. In one case the top of the lowest element is limited to the lower half only.

Did I mention... suggestions more than welcome.

[image]

Comment: "things start fighting each other" - that's a sign you need to think through your layout's priorities. Instead of thinking about iPad, iPhone, landscape, portrait, it can be easier to think as if you're designing a website that can be resized at will. What's your *ideal* layout if there's plenty of space? Build that first with high-priority (750) constraints. Then think about how those constraints will be invalid at small widths and heights - what other constraints can you add to still unambiguously define a layout? Those constraints should be added as low-priority constraints (250).

Comment: If you have a sample project that's close, please post your code or upload the project here. I'm happy to give more specific feedback on a partial implementation.